# How do I read this array of arrays?

Tags: php, arrays

Kind of new to PHP.. I am having a very basic issue.

Here is my array structure. (there is 0,1,2,3,4,5 but I only included [0])

```
[0] => Array (
    [mid] => 32
    [uid] => 1
    [username] => ufcadmin
    [mediakey] => b25b3513de4c21277a1af083bc486dc2
    [mediatype] => 0
    [first] => false
    [hidden] => false
    [status] => 5
    [featured] => false
    [culture] => en
    [properties] => a:7:{s:12:”source-width”;i:720;s:13:”source-height”;i:480;s:15:”source-duration”;i:460;s:5:”width”;i:720;s:6:”height”;i:480;s:8:”duration”;i:460;s:8:”filesize”;i:30343114;}
    [title] => Cardio & Core
    [description] => FIT Workout #8
    [duration] => 460
    [thumbnail_filename] => http://192.168.10.131/images/thumbs/b25b3513de4c21277a1af083bc486dc2_1405381634.jpg
    [source_filename] => http://192.168.10.131/images/source/b25b3513de4c21277a1af083bc486dc2_1405381634.avi
    [scrambled_filename] => http://192.168.10.131/images/media/b25b3513de4c21277a1af083bc486dc2_1405381634.mp4 
)
```

I am trying to parse the code with the following php..

```
    $y = 0;     
    foreach($contentoutput[$y] as $media) {
          echo '<pre>';
         // print_r($key);
         //echo ":";
         // print_r($value);
         echo "Title: " . $media['title'];
         $y++;
     }
```

Unfortunately, my code is returning..

```
        Title: C

        Title: <

        Title: 4

        Title: h

        Title: h

        Title: h

        Title: 

        Title: 

        Title: 

        Title: 

        Title: 

        Title: 

        Title: 0

        Title: 6

        Title: 0

        Title: 0

        Title: 0

        Title: 0

        Title: 2

        Title: 2

        Title: 

        Title: 

        Title:
```

Is there something wrong with my foreach?

Comment: ate you sure your showing us `$contentoutput[0]`

Comment: `foreach($contentoutput as $media) {`, no need in `$y` at all.

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
foreach($contentoutput as $media) {
```

You are taking each key from the array and trying to output $media['title'].
ie: `32['title']`, `1['title']`, etc

If you want to just display the title for the first record, do `echo $contentoutput[0]['title']`

Comment: Do you want to ouput the title for the first record, or all of them?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to index the $contentoutput in the foreaech.

Do like this:

```
foreach ($contentoutput as $i => $media) {
    echo "Title $i: " . $media['title'];
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Your foreach is the issue, as I see it.  `$media` will represent the various keys in your array (mid, uid, title, etc.) and you're effectively saying "Give me `$contentoutput[0]["mid"]["title"]`".  Try this instead:

```
$y = 0;     
foreach($contentoutput[$y] as $k => $media) {
     if($k != "title") continue;
      echo '<pre>';
     // print_r($key);
     //echo ":";
     // print_r($value);
     echo "Title: " . $media;
     $y++;
 }
```